# Are there accepted linux tools for AOM/y1731?

Tags: networking

Are there industry accepted tools for regular linux distributions to work with AOM, specifically y1731 link traces?

I can only find academic experiments.

Comment: What do you mean by "work with"? And what criterion does an "industry-accepted tool" fulfil?  Wireshark can allegedly do [_something_](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/c/cfm.html) with this, but it's unclear whether you want a list of tools (which would be more or less off-topic as no single answer would be authoritative and final), or if you wish to solve _a particular issue_ (which would be a more _interesting_ question to read the answers to).

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks for the feedback. I might be over my head here. I'm setting 802.3ah interfaces. I would like to do basic "client actions" on them, such as setting link failure and other link events. And ultimately do a trace over a network of links/interfaces. I was hopping there would already be a accepted distro package like `ip` for non-aom l2 stuff

Comment: Consider adding this info to your question as clarification as to what it is you actually want to do.